# initialize php object of type ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor()

Tags: php

i am trying to create an object using the php Reflection class but i can't figure out how to initialize it.
as shown in the following code:

```
          $obj = new \ReflectionClass('CLASS NAME');
          $inst = $obj->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
          foreach($row as $key => $value){
             $obj->$key = $value;
          }
          return $obj;
```

i get the following error:`ReflectionException: Cannot set read-only property ReflectionClass::$name`

Comment: added an update..hopefully will describe the issue better

Comment: I glanced at the revision history and see a reference to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` in there. Are you trying to avoid calling the constructor on a fetched object, or avoid calling it after properties are already set? Are you aware of [the `FETCH_PROPS_LATE` fetch mode option](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php#98876)?

Comment: Given the code you have above, `$inst` is the instantiated object, while `$obj` is the `ReflectionClass`. So in your loop you should be assigning properties on `$inst->key`.